# Работают ли C-шные библиотеки в arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Работают ли C-шные библиотеки в Arduino? По сути там C-Образный язык, но немного переделанный. Не знаю, будут ли работать библиотеки из C/C++/C# в  Arduino IDE.

Если вы знаете, работают они там или нет, то напишите. Если работают, то с какого из выше указанных языков можно брать библиотеки и как их использовать в Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Язык wiring (язык arduino) — это С++ без библиотек std, stl и исключений + собственная библиотека для доступа к железу. Компилируется скетч компилятором языка с++ — gcc.

Поэтому можно включить в сектч всё, что написано на С и С++, кроме некоторых новых наворотов и указанных выше ограничений.

Но есть серьёзное ограничение по объёму памяти, так что не любая библиотека влезет в чип.